# How do I place the image next to the text without exceeding the screen?

Tags: html, css

[Here is the picture i need to embed in the website!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OZiQ.jpg)I am trying to position the picture next to the text, but I don't know how to adjust the margin to make the text floats to the left without leaving a large white space next to it. Also, probably because the picture is too big, the web page keeps exceeding the screen area and the browser gives me the scroll bar down below. How should I solve this?

I want it to look like this website: http://alexbudak.com/#first

Here is my code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title> Larry Rosenburg Official Website </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Anton|Crimson+Text:400,700,700i|Rakkas" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Cherry+Swash|Cinzel|Gentium+Basic|Muli" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Arsenal" rel="stylesheet">
    </head>

    <body>
        <header>
            <div id="logo">
                <img src ="lincoln.jpg" width ="30%" alt="Lincoln logo" id="logo_picture">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li> <a href="index.html"> Home </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="lincoln.html"> Lincoln </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="about.html"> About </a> </li>
                        <li> <a href="contact.html"> Contact </a> </li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>

            </div>
        </header>


        <div id="name">
            <p>
                Larry Rosenburg
            </p> 
        </div>
        <div id="profile-pic">
            <img src="placeholder.jpg" width="30%" alt="" >
        </div>


    </body>

    <footer>
    </footer>

</html>
```

And here is the css:

```
#logo_picture{
    margin-left: 80px;
}

#logo img, #logo nav{
    float: left;
}
#logo nav{
    line-height: 120px;
    margin-left: 250px;
}
nav ul{
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0 10px;
    padding: 0;

}

nav li{
    display: inline;
}

nav a{
    color: black;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family:'Arsenal', 'sans-serif';
    font-weight: 300;
    padding: 2px 38px;
    text-decoration:none;
}

nav a, nav a:visited {
    color: black;
}

nav a.selected, nav a:hover{
    color: grey;
}


    #name{
        margin: 100px 500px 0 10%;
        font-size: 59px;
        font-family: 'Anton', 'sans-serif';
        float: left;
        max-width: 500px;

    }

    #profile-pic{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The best solution here is actually to set the image as background of the parent element.

The example link you sent does something convoluted by having an `img` element but hiding it and using the src attribute.

However, if you resize the browser you will see that the image and text overlap on small screens. Thus, they are not neighboring elements but a text and a background.

```css
#name{
  background: url(https://static1.squarespace.com/static/541ff355e4b03f1e8815bc58/t/55c0b5abe4b0ec33f39abc7e/1438692796595/Try+1.jpg);
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 40%;
  height: 300px;
}

#name p{
    margin: 100px 500px 0 10%;
    font-size: 59px;
    font-family: 'Anton', 'sans-serif';
    max-width: 500px;
}
```

```html
<div id="name">
    <p>
        Larry Rosenburg
    </p> 
</div>
```

Comment: it does not work with my header. Is there a way to just adjust the margin to position them?

Comment: Where is your header? Who are "them"?

Comment: Here is everything:

Comment: Don't do that. Delete both of your comments and add the code to your original question. If you need me to see your header image then you'll also have to host it somewhere or upload to SO.

Comment: Upload your image as well so that I can see it and customize the answer.

Comment: I just added the picture

Answer (score 0):

Hope this is what you wanted to achieve.

Try the below snippet once.

```css
#imageContainer {
  height: 500px;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
}
#image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: relative;
}
#image img {
  float: right;
}
#nameContainer {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="imageContainer">
  <div id="image">
    <img src="http://www.mobileswall.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/300-Merry-Christmas-Minions-l.jpg"></img>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="nameContainer">
  <p>
    Hi i'm Nikhilesh
  </p>
</div>
```